# MaxClique is DP-hard

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, time-complexity

I want to show that

> MAX−CLIQUE={(G,k)|the largest clique of G is of size exactly k} is
>   DP-complete

The idea is reduce MAX-CLIQUE to

> C={(G1,k1,G2,k2) | G1 has a k1-clique and G2 does not have any
>   k2-clique}

which I already know is DP-hard.

I was seeing the solution on the second page of this [link](https://www7.in.tum.de/um/courses/complexity/SS11/exercises/ex04-sol.pdf), but it seems that there is a mistake in the fifth paragraph, since the graph that builds G′_1, is equal to the product tensor of the path of cardinality k1 with the graph G1, so the clique number is the minimum of the clique numbers of the factors. And this always gives 2, since every path has a clique number equal to 2.

Comment: What if you replace the path by a clique?

Comment: Thank you! But what path do you mean?

Comment: What you call a chain. The common term is "path".

Comment: Oh, I get it now. I think that solves it! Thank you very much!

Comment: Can I invite you to write an answer to your own question, explaining the full solution in a way that will be useful to others who might have the same question?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take:

For every $(G_1,k_1,G_2,k_2)$ we make $(G_3,k_3)$ that satisfies:
$$ (G_1,k_1,G_2,k_2) \in C  \longleftrightarrow  (G_3,k_3) \in \textit{MAX-CLIQUE}$$
For this to happen, $G_3$ should have a maximum clique of size $k_3$ only if $G_1$ has a clique of size $k_1$ and $G_2$ not having a $k_2$ clique.($G_3$ should not have a maximum $k_3$ clique because of $G_2$)

Now considering these three observations:

1. If a graph $G=(V,E)$ have a clique of size $n$, one can make a graph $G'=(V',E')$ to have a maximum clique of size $n$:
   $$ V' =  \{ (i,v)| i \in \{1,2,\cdots,k \} \text{ and } v \in V \}$$
   $$ E' = \{\{(i,v),(j,u)\}| i \neq j \text{ and } (i,v) \in V' \text{ and } (j,u) \in V' \text{ and } \{v,u\} \in E \} $$
   (Consider it as a $k$ cluster; edges are between two different clusters and there's no edge inside each cluster. With Pigeonhole principle, one can show this works.) (Symbol $^kG$)
2. If a graph $G=(V,E)$ has a maximum $k\text{-clique}$, one can make $G'=(V',E')$ to have a maximum clique of size $k+x$. Here's the procedure:
   $$ V' =  V \cup \{X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_x | \forall 1\leq i\leq x, X_i \not \in V   \} $$
   $$ E' = E \cup \{ \{X_i,X_j\} | 1\leq j \leq x \text{ and } 1\leq i \leq x \text{ and } i \neq j \} \cup \{ \{X_i,v\} | v \in V \text{ and } 1\leq i \leq x \} $$
   (It's just adding a $x$ clique to the graph and connecting each of $x$ clique vertexes to all others )(Symbol $_xG$)
3. If a graph $G=(V,E)$ has a maximum $k\text{-clique}$, one can make $G'=(V',E')$ to have a maximum clique of size $2k$. This is because the new graph $G'$ will have a $(2k-1)\text{-clique}$ if and only if $G'$ has a $2k\text{-clique}$. Here's the procedure:
   $$ V' =  \{ (i,v)| i \in \{1,2\} \text{ and } v \in V \} $$
   $$ E' = \{\{(i,v),(i,u)\}| i \in \{1,2\} \text{ and } \{u,v\} \in E \} \cup \{\{(i,v),(j,u)\}| i,j \in \{1,2\} \text{ and } i \neq j \text{ and } u,v \in V \} $$
   (It's just like making another copy of $G$ and connecting all nodes to another one. And it can be proved by contradiction. Assuming that $G'$ has a $2k-1$ clique but no $2k$ clique.) (Symbol $G^2$)

There're two possibilities to make $(G_3,k_3)$:

1. $2k_2 > k_1 \rightarrow G_3=(G_2^2)\cup(_{(2k_2-k_1-1)}(^{k_1}G_1))$ and $k_3=2k_2-1$
2. $2k_2 \leq k_1 \rightarrow G_3=(_{k_1 -2k_2+1}(G_2^2)) \cup ((^{k_1}G_1))$ and $k_3=k_1$

And link for [Graph union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_operations#Binary_operations). Also, it's trivial to show that it can be done polynomially.